# Connecting a Java application to an SQL database in IBM Bluemix

Tags: java, sql, database, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have created a Bluemix app that has a small SQL Database. I want to access the database from my site with API calls. I am new to Java so I used the starter code provided in the Liberty for Java runtime and followed the "[tutorial](https://hub.jazz.net/project/pvanrun/SQLDBJava/overview)" linked in the Bluemix Docs. I copied only the SQLDBSample.java file from the tutorial.

I am having a lot of trouble in getting the SQL connection code to run. I kept the `@WebServlet("/SQLDBSample")` and am unable to get the code to run even if I go to `myapp.mybluemix.net/SQLDBSample.` I just want to get API routes set up and be able to do AJAX calls within the site JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the name. I am using the regular SQL Database. When using the Sample .war file, it seemed to work fine, but I can't seem to call the function myself using the starter code and the sample java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these answers ended up working for me. I found no real solution so I switched to Node.js and got it working in minutes. I'd recommend using Node if you're using BlueMix. It's simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudant is not a SQL database. If you want to use the SQLDB example, you need to bind your app to the "SQL Database" service, not to Cloudant.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the below link. It describes in detail about connectivity between java code and db2(sqldb), which explains various operations like binding to sqldb, examining vcap_services and more.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-sqldb-app/

Answer (score 0):

Two options to help you get started with Java and Cloudant NoSQL DB.

1) In the Bluemix UI, click on Catalog and create a Java Cloudant boilerplate. After you create your application, you can download the starter code and learn it

2) Read [Java and Cloudant NoSQL DB on Bluemix](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/07/08/cloudant_on_bluemix/) blog post by @Sai-Vennam which describes the auto-configuration in detail.